# C problem requires to find students semester propably from year and age

Tags: c, if-statement, modulo

I have an exercise where I have as input the name, the age and the current university year of whoever, and it asks the minimum years for him to graduate, the person's age when he graduates and how many semesters till the graduation. How can we find the semester the person is in? Thought I had found a way but it duplicates logical expressions so it's not corrects.

```
/*My attempt*/
if(age % 2 == 1 && year == 1 || age % 2 == 0 && year == 1)
    semester = 1;
else if(age % 2 == 0 && year == 1 || age % 2 == 1 && year == 1)
    semester = 2;
else if(age % 2 == 0 && year == 2 || age % 2 == 1 && year == 2)
    semester = 3;
else if(age % 2 == 1 && year == 2 || age % 2 == 0 && year == 2)
    semester = 4;
else if(age % 2 == 1 && year == 3 || age % 2 == 0 && year == 3)
    semester = 5;
else if(age % 2 == 0 && year == 3 || age % 2 == 1 && year == 3)
    semester = 6;
else if(age % 2 == 0 && year == 4 || age % 2 == 1 && year == 4)
    semester = 7;
else if(age % 2 == 1 && year == 4 || age % 2 == 0 && year == 4)
    semester = 8;
```

Comment: You are repeating each if case twice (just flipping the order).  You will never hit the cases where semester is an even number.  Also, why do you check age at all?  You are checking if it is odd or even so that will always be true.

Comment: There isn't sufficient information. The fact that Joe is a 35 year old student in his 3rd year tells us nothing about the number of semesters he has until he graduates. (Well, if you assume a 4-year program, it tells narrows down the possibilities to 3 or 4, but that's it.)

Comment: This is a lot of branching. I would break everything down to units of semesters, do some math, then convert semesters to years to figure out how much time is left until graduation and how old the student will be then. But ikegami is right, you need to know the current semester in the current year to really answer when the student will graduate.

Comment: Yes that's where I ended up at, that there is insufficient data